# Mutate column with dynamics (dplyr ot data.table)

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Could you help me please? How to add to a dataframe a column with dynamics, using mutate function of dplyr, or data.table library?

For example, we have this dataframe:

```
name  sum
а      3
b      7
c      13
d      11
e      16
```

And we need a column "dynamics" with the difference between the sum in the current row and the sum in the previous row:

```
name  sum     dynamics
a      3      -
b      7      4
c      13     6
d      11     -2
e      16     5
```

The 1-st row doesn't have previous row (so it is "-"), for second row dynamics is equal to 7-3=4, for 3-d is equal to 13-7=6 and so on.

I tries different variants, for example:

```
df %>% mutate(dynamics = value - value[-1])
```

but this doesn't work.

How to write this correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try `df$dynamics<-c(NA,diff(df$sum))`, or in `dplyr` use `lag(value)`

Answer (score 0):

Input

```
dat =data.table(name = letters[1:5], sum=c(3,7,13,11,16))
```

data.table

```
dat[, dynamics:=sum - shift(sum)][]
```

Or, using dplyr:

```
dat %>% mutate(dynamics = sum - lag(sum))
```

Output:

```
   name sum dynamics
1:    a   3       NA
2:    b   7        4
3:    c  13        6
4:    d  11       -2
5:    e  16        5
```